# Recursion and order of statements execution

Tags: ruby, memory-management, recursion, trace

This question deals with how the statements and those involving recursion are executed, and in what order Ruby will handle the,.  Specifically, as I've been learning online, I have found that Ruby does not follow Last in first out convention in a stack form of memory-management, but rather has a garbage collector.  I have numbered questions at the bottom after all the code.  I hope I have made everything clear, but please let me know what parts of the question may need improvement.  Thank you.

```
def append(array, n)
return array if n < 0 #base case, how we end this thing
    array <<  n*2    #Line No. 1 

append(array, n - 1) #Line No. 2 
    array <<  n*2    #Line No. 3

end


append( [], 3)


#output  [6,4,2,0,0,2,4,6]
```

The two lines below give the output of `[6,4,2,0]`

```
array <<  n*2    #Line No. 1 

append(array, n - 1) #Line No. 2
```

When the order of the two statements are reversed the output is `[0,2,4,6]`

```
 append(array, n - 1) #Line No. 2 
    array <<  n*2    #Line No. 3
```

1. In the original append method (top section of code), why does ruby stop to compute at the first recursive call, continue on to line 3, and then do the second recursive call, then concatenate the output of both recursions?
2. If line 2 and line 3 were the only part of the recursion the output would be`[0,2,4,6]`, in ascending order.  What is the convention that Ruby uses in its execution?  Why does this code not give the output `[6,4,2,0]`, since the `n-1` is being called before `array << n*2`?
3. Is there a proper definition or programming theory as to how these recursive calls are handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is doing nothing unusual here, any more than any other "typical" computer language.

> In the original append method (top section of code), why does ruby stop to compute at the first recursive call, continue on to line 3, and then do the second recursive call, then concatenate the output of both recursions?

I don't see any evidence for this. The first half of the output `6,4,2,0` is from Line 1. The second half `0,2,4,6` is from Line 3. Note that the first time it falls through to Line 3 is when `n==0`. So the next value after `6,4,2,0` is `0`, then `2`, `4`, and finally `6`. It pops out of the call stack, LIFO, just like any other computer language.

> If line 2 and line 3 were the only part of the recursion the output would be[0,2,4,6], in ascending order. What is the convention that Ruby uses in its execution? Why does this code not give the output [6,4,2,0], since the n-1 is being called before array << n*2?

Because it has to call `append` 4 times before it returns to fall through to Line 3. By this time, `n=0` which is why `0` is still first in this case.

> Is there a proper definition or programming theory as to how these recursive calls are handled?

It's just LIFO. Give it some more thought.

If you're still not convinced, here is C++ code that prints the exact same sequence:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

list<int>& append( list<int> &array, int n )
{
    if( n < 0 ) return array;
    array.push_back(n*2);
    append( array, n-1 );
    array.push_back(n*2);
    return array;
}

int main()
{
    list<int> array;
    append( array, 3 );
    for( int& x : array ) cout << x << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```